# Как изменяется глагол "прочувствовать" в форме деепричастия?

Tags: морфология

Как изменяется слово "прочувствовать"?

Правильно ли употребление "прочувствывая"? (что делая?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально (и нормативно) от глагола *прочувствовать* образовать только невозвратное деепричастие совершенного вида  *прочувствовав*.

Однако народ активно пользуется недостающей ему формой глагола:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1) Правильно: **прочувств/ова/ть ― прочувств/ова/в.**

**Примеры:**

Уже в Праге, еще раз **прочувствовав** глубину времени и увидев впереди свое прошлое, сказал... [Анатолий Азольский. . 2000]

Промокнув до нитки, сквозь бурелом, колючий ельник, чавкающую под ногами травяную жижу мы выбрались к проклятой узкоколейке, еще раз не разумом, кожей **прочувствовав:** это единственный для нас путь на свободу. [Анатолий Приставкин. **Вагончик мой дальний** (2005)]

2) В приведенных в предыдущем ответе примерах  **явное грамматическое отступление от правил**. Всё дело в том, глагол ***прочувствовать*** не имеет видовой пары, то есть нет глагола ***прочувствывать***, поэтому нет и деепричастия ***прочувствывая***.

Кроме всего прочего, глаголы с суффиксом ОВА обычно образуют видовую пару **по следующей схеме**: рис/ова/ть ― разрис/ов/ыва/ть - разрис/ова/в.

3) Поэтому это в лучшем случае **авторский грамматический окказионализм.**

Как видно по тексту, автору было важно изобразить длящееся действие, а для этого нужен глагол несовершенного вида

Comment: Надо написать Ю. Никитину и спросить,  что он думает по поводу своих грамматических вольностей. У меня есть его книга "Как стать писателем в наше время" на тему литературного мастерства.  Интересное пособие для молодых писателей.

Comment: _Sharon: Правильно: прочувствовать - прочувствуя._  
https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-58846.htm ===

Я очень редко нажимаю на кнопку "Ответ не является полезным". Сейчас вынужден был это сделать, увидев, что Ваш ответ начал набирать "плюсы". Ответ неверен, но дело даже не в этом. Плохо то, что Вы раскручиваете в своём ответе сайт, которому совершенно НЕЛЬЗЯ доверять  из-за огромного числа ошибок в приводимой им "Полной акцентуированной парадигмы по А. А. Зализняку". Вы же тиражируете ошибки этого сайта… Для справки: НЕТ У ЗАЛИЗНЯКА ФОРМЫ "ПРОЧУВСТВУЯ".

Comment: Да, это ужасно. Я как раз подумала, успею ли я исправить ответ, пока ВЫ (или еще кто-то) не нажмете кнопочку. Всё-таки не успела. Кстати, Вы не хотите уж заодно дать оценку форме "прочувствывая", а то мы и ее РАСТИРАЖИРУЕМ И РАСКРУТИМ. Честно говоря, я машинально списала у "мнимого" Зализняка ошибочную форму (чисто для справки), основное внимание уделив анализу грамматического окказионализма (к сожалению, в этом анализе Вы ничего полезного не увидели). Но пока я прогуливалась по вечернему парку нашего  города, какие-то ангелы нашептали мне: "Иди и быстро проверь текст". Вот такая история. –